# How to get the substring after nth occurrence of character in a string in Amazon marketing cloud

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get the substring after the nth occurrence of a character in a string in **Amazon marketing cloud**.

I haven't found any documentation by Amazon on their sql syntax. It's known to be similar to PostgreSQL however.

Example:
Trying to get the substring after the second underscore '_'

```
Input: str1_str2_str3_str4

Desired output would be:
str3
```

Any help here will be very appreciated.

Comment: *I haven't found any documentation by Amazon on their sql syntax.*: do you mean [Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/index.html) maybe?

Comment: Amazon Marketing Cloud

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are running Amazon Redshift, you can use [`split_part`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html):

```
select input, split_part(input, '_', 3) part3
from mytable
```